# Silent Sinon stub error throwing in my Mocha test report

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I would like to silent every `Error` thrown by a stubbed function.
For example this code block :

```js
it(`should return a JSON object containing an error message and a status code of
            "${BAD_REQUEST}" if the request was unsuccessful.`, (done) => {

    const errMsg = 'Could not fetch users.';

    sandbox.stub(UserDao.prototype, 'getAll').throws(new Error(errMsg));

    agent.get(getUsersPath)
          .end((err: Error, res: Response) => {
              expect(res.status).to.equal(BAD_REQUEST);
              expect(res.body.error)
              expect(res.body.error).to.equal(errMsg);
              done();
          });
    });
```

Is giving me the following output:

```
User Routes
    "GET:/api/users/all"
      ✓ should return a JSON object with all the users and a status code of "200" if the
            request was successful.
Error: Could not fetch users.
    at Context.it (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/tests/Users.spec.ts:67:62)
    at callFnAsync (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:385:21)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:329:7)
    at Runner.runTest (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:625:10)
    at /Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:749:12
    at next (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:542:14)
    at /Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:552:7
    at next (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:453:14)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/qeude/dev/categories-game-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:520:5)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      ✓ should return a JSON object containing an error message and a status code of
            "400" if the request was unsuccessful.
```

It's a bit annoying to get the error thrown by the stub for each test, I can't find a way to silent this.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Use catch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch or try and catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your production code is using some logger that just logs all errors. Probably just `console.error`.

In different projects and circumstances, i've empolyed two strategies:

- silence all errors for **successfull** tests (because for failed you may be interested in any kind of hint about error)
- stub logger and expect that this error is really caught and logged

So, the first solution in `mocha` BDD might look like this:

```js
// somewhere in global test module and/or offending suite
beforeEach(() => {
    TheGlobalLogger.redirectToBuffer();
});
afterEach(() => {
    if (this.currentTest.state !== "passed") {
        console.log("--- dumping logs from failed test ---");
        TheGlobalLogger.dumpBufferedLogs();
    }
    TheGlobalLogger.disableRedirectToBuffer()
});
```

Of course, `TheGlobalLogger` can use any method to capture `console` logs or whatever other mechanism you use.

You can also decorate particular flows with expectation about logs. Example from other project:

```js
   it("...", () => {
     assertWillLogSync(() => {
       // some code that ultimately provoke console.warn with particular message
       console.warn("error: fooBar"),
     },
     console, "warn", /error: fooBar/
   );
```

In your case, you would need `async` version of this. Example of [assertWillLogSync](https://github.com/heremaps/harp.gl/blob/master/%40here/harp-test-utils/lib/TestUtils.ts#L170) implementation.